# django как сделать страницу просмотра логов

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Логи пишу через библиотека logging лежат в папке logs
Вопрос. Как мне в админку добавить страницу. Без модели. Произвольную страницу. Чтобы я там например вывел логи и какую нить простую формочку для поиска / фильтра сделать

может есть какая то заготовка?

Answer (score 0):

Создание кастомной страницы в админ панели мало чем отличается от создания обычной странице на `django`. Вопрос достаточно обширный и я напишу тезисно, что надо сделать, относительно вашего какого-то приложения (`views.py`, `urls.py`)

1. Во `views.py` пишете обычное представление

   ```py
   from django.shortcuts import rende

   def show_admin_panel_custom(request):
       context = {'data': 'test'}
       return render(request, 'any_path/admin_panel_custom.html', context)
   ```
2. Создаете шаблон `admin_panel_custom.html` и наследуете его от `admin/base_site.html`. Пример

   ```html
   {% extends 'admin/base_site.html' %}
   ....
   ```
3. Определим URLs в `urls.py`

   ```py
   from django.conf.urls import url
   from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
   from any_path.views show_admin_panel_custom

   urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^admin-added-page/$', user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)(show_admin_panel_custom), name='show_admin_panel_custom'),
    ]
   ```

В общем, то, и все. Не забудьте прокинуть URLы приложения до URLов проекта и по ссылке `http://localhost:8000/admin-added-page` вам будет доступна страничка, причем если вы обратите внимание на ссылку, то я сразу ограничил доступ к ней только для суперпользователя. `any_path` - это путь до приложения и необходимо прописать ваше значение

Далее, есть несколько путей добавления ссылки в админке на эту страницу, но это отдельный вопрос и с этим вам уже будет под силу разобраться